# Core Plot: Cursor does not adjust over CPTGraphHostingView

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-plot, appkit

I use Core Plot in two macOS apps (first one is old, second one is new). Each of them has a `CPTGraphHostingView` where some plots are displayed. I can click, hold and drag to change the visible area.

In the first app, when I hoover over the plot, the cursor changes to an open hand. It also changes to a closed hand when I drag. This is what I want, and this is the behaviour in all the sample apps of Core Plot.

In the second app, the cursor always stays the same (arrow).

**Edit**: Here is a screenshot of the view hierarchy in Xcode (views behind the plot view are hidden). There is no view in front of the `CPTGraphHostingView`, just a few controls are higher in the view hierarchy, but they are positioned around the plot.

[image: view hierachy]

I was not able to find any difference between my two apps (or the second app and the example apps) that could cause this. Both apps compile with Xcode 10.1 and Core Plot release-2.3 branch.

What should I look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `initWithFrame` of `CPTGraphHostingView` does not get called in my second app, the hand cursers are always `nil` and cannot be adjusted. This is from Apple's docs for "[Creating a Custom View](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html)":

> View instances that are created in Interface Builder don't call
>   initWithFrame: when their nib files are loaded, which often causes
>   confusion. Remember that Interface Builder archives an object when it
>   saves a nib file, so the view instance will already have been created
>   and initWithFrame: will already have been called.
>
> The awakeFromNib method provides an opportunity to provide
>   initialization of a view when it is created as a result of a nib file
>   being loaded. When a nib file that contains a view object is loaded,
>   each view instance receives an awakeFromNib message when all the
>   objects have been unarchived. This provides the object an opportunity
>   to initialize any attributes that are not archived with the object in
>   Interface Builder.

So I subclassed `CPTGraphHostingView` and loaded the cursors from `NSCursor` in `awakeFromNib`, using the advice from Eric Skroch:

MyGraphHostingView.h:

```
#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyGraphHostingView : CPTGraphHostingView

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

MyGraphHostingView.m:

```
#import "MyGraphHostingView.h"

@implementation MyGraphHostingView

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    if (!self.closedHandCursor) {
        self.closedHandCursor  = [NSCursor closedHandCursor];
    }
    if (!self.openHandCursor) {
        self.openHandCursor    = [NSCursor openHandCursor];
    }
    self.allowPinchScaling = YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that there aren't any other invisible views obscuring the Core Plot hosting view. Does everything else in the second app (layout, appearance, etc.) work the way you expect?

Comment: I looked at the view hierarchy, but there is no view in front of the plot view. Everything else works as expected. I added a picture of the view hierarchy to my question.

Comment: Core Plot sets the cursor rect on the hosting view. Check for anything else in the view hierarchy that might be capturing the cursor or overwriting the Core Plot settings.

Comment: I found that `initWithFrame` of `CPTGraphHostingView` does not get called in my second app, so the hand cursers are always `nil`. It gets called in my first app. So far I have no idea why. I then subclassed `CPTGraphHostingView` and loaded the cursors from `NSCursor` in `awakeFromNib`. This works. Do you think there will be some side effects from `initWithFrame` not getting called? You do some additional initialisation there. This issue is discussed in Apple's docs for "Creating a Custom View".

Comment: That should work. You may also want to set `allowPinchScaling` to `YES` to enable pinch gestures on a trackpad.

Comment: This is a good advice, thank you. If you update your answer accordingly I can accept it.